# If a variable counting hundredths of a second is stored in a signed long 32-bit integer

Tags: variables, integer, decimal, long-integer, integer-overflow

If a variable counting hundredth of a second is stored in a signed long 32-bit integer,
how many days, to two decimals, will it take until that integer overflows?

Comment: I'm confused by: "_a long 32-bit integer_".  In most modern compilers, `long` would usually refer to a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Regardless, a signed 32-bit integer has a maximum value of `2147483647`.  It's not difficult to calculate the result to the question knowing that

Comment: @Martin Please explain the solution.

Comment: I'm really not certain why it's problematic but I've answered below to show how to calculate it

Answer (score 0):

Forgoing the nomenclature regarding "*long*" vs "*32-bit integer*", assuming you mean a `signed 32-bit integer`, this is simple to calculate as follows:

1. Signed 32-bit integer has a maximum value of `2,147,483,647`.
2. When storing 1/100ths of a second, this gives a maximum value of `21,474,836.47` seconds.
3. There are `86,400` seconds in a day - `60 x 60 x 24 = 86,400`.
4. The value in days is therefore `21,474,836.47 / 86,400 = 248.5513480...`.
5. This value to 2dp is `248.55`.

Again:

```
  2147483647    ' Signed 32-bit integer max value
/        100    ' Divide by 100 to get value in seconds
=   21474836.47
/      86400    ' Divide this by seconds in a day
=        248.55 ' Days (rounded to 2dp)
```

Alternatively you could simply have divided by hundredths of a seconds in a day (`8,640,000`) to get the same result:

```
  2147483647    ' Signed 32-bit integer max value
/    8640000    ' Divide by hundredths of a second in a day
=        248.55 ' Days (rounded to 2dp)
```

Of course, if you actually meant a "*long*" (a `signed 64-bit integer`) then the answer becomes the significantly larger `1,067,519,911,673.01`days (2dp) which is the equivalent of nearly 3 billion years!